# Passing single and double quotes both in JavaScript function parameter from jstl (much tricky)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, parameter-passing, jstl-functions

I know this looks silly to ask, but I got a situation where I have to pass parameters to a javascript function, and these parameters are of `String` type.

The issue with data is, the data can have `single Quote` or `Double quote`

e.g.

"TEST", `TEST` or `TEST`. This is coming from the database.

**here is my JSTL call on click.**

The 2nd parameter value is 
`ANOTHER " company"` which is the actual root cause.

**I tried JSTL `fn: replace(.....)`** method as well but not succeed.

**Note:** The value also could be `'ANOTHER' Company`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
  onclick="return showPopUp('${account.fName}','${fn:replace(account.lName, "\'","\\\'")}','${fn:replace(account.compName, "\'", "\\\'")}','${account.firstTimePin}','${account.email}');return false;">
</a>
```

this generates the following HTML code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
   target="_self" 
   onclick="return showPopup('CRUISE  ','ANOTHER " company"','123456','user@directbiller.com');">
</a>
```

and here is my javascript function

```
function showPopup(param1,param2,param3,param4){
  // busness logic
}
```

The issue is invalid call/syntax to call `showPopup()` method.

Comment: Why downvoted? if it is too simple then give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode it with `&quot;`.

```js
function showPopup() { console.log(arguments); }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" 
    onclick="return showPopup('CRUISE  ','ANOTHER &quot; company&quot;','123456','user@directbiller.com');">
    Link
</a>
```

Just add another replace term, i.e.

```
fn:replace(fn:replace(account.compName, "\"", "&quot;"), "\'", "\\\'")
```

Comment: Dear, I can not put `&quot;` because the parameters are not hardcoded, these are dynamic values which may or may not have quotes.

Comment: So? You can just run a `replace` on it.

Comment: Yes, I did it as well. Might be my HTML code is confusing. u can see in JSTL part.

Comment: No you didn't. You just replaced single quotes.

Comment: That's the loophole. The value can have a single or double quote. any.

Comment: Just run another replace, it's not that hard. Something like:`fn:replace(fn:replace(account.compName, "\"", "&quot;"), "\'", "\\\'")`

Comment: yeah, I'll try this.

Comment: Nope, While showing the value in textBox, it's displaying like `ANOTHER &quote;COMPANY&quote;`

Comment: It's `&quot;` not `&quote;`.

Comment: Thanks, please update your answer so that I can Accept it.

Comment: You could accept it either way, because the key part here is to simply encode the quotes. But whatever...